# How to transform (KD) number into win percentage in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, math

I need to calculate a win loss ratio from my app in PHP (Laravel 5.2)

I have these two numbers:

```
$array['WinLoss'] = $array['GamesWon'] / $array['TotalGamesLost'];
```

Which gives me:

```
Win: 480

Loss: 400
```

I tried doing this in my view:

```
{{ round((float)$WinLoss * 100) . '%' }}
```

but it gives me 120%. Thats obviously not correct, it should be around 58%

How would I calculate to show around 58% not 120%?

Comment: Note: It would probably be best to perform this action in your controller. The view should ideally not have to deal with any actual calculations, keeping it clean and mostly related to actual view related stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $array['WinLoss'] = round(100 * ($array['GamesWon'] / ($array['TotalGamesLost'] + $array['GamesWon'])), 2);
```

would give you % of games won

Comment: Yes thank you, I will mark as correct when it allows me to